# ionic app error while building Android APK

Tags: ionic-framework

I am getting the error while building the ionic app ,ionic-app-script is missing.How to add 'ionic-app-script' file in ionic 2 project? what is the purpose of this file?

Answer (score 1):

just delete `platform` folder and run 
`ionic cordova build android --release --prod`